# Drawing dotted line on a plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to draw vertical and horizontal dotted lines on a plot with two functions and apparently I can't get the code necessary to work. I need the lines to be where `n = 2` and `f(n) = 2`. Can anyone please show me how it's done?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[font={footnotesize,it},width=.5\textwidth]{caption}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0:5, samples=50,grid=major, 
legend style={legend cell align=left, font=\tiny},
restrict y to domain=0:5,xlabel=$\text{Dimensione dell'input}$,
ylabel=$\text{Tempo di esecuzione}$, 
legend pos=north west]
\addplot [color=red]    {x};
\addplot [color=green]  {e^x-5/2*x};

\legend{$n$, $e^n-\frac{5}{2}n$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{In figura $f(n) = n$ e $g(n) = e^n-\frac{5}{2}n$.}
\label{gif:asymsup}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a compilable code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To draw a dotted line, do

```
\draw [dotted] (x1,y1) -- (x2,y2);
```

For the vertical line, the `x` coordinates are both `2`. You can add suitable y-coordinates manually, or to automatically get the axis limits, use `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}` and similar for `ymax`.

For the horizontal line, use the fact that calculations are allowed in coordinates, so you can use `e^2-5/2*2` for the y-coordinates directly. The x-values are obtained in the same way as mentioned above.

Hence, something like

```
\draw [very thick,dotted] (2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
\draw [very thick,dotted] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},e^2-5/2*2) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},e^2-5/2*2);
```

Two things to note:

1. Add the above commands inside the `axis` environment.
2. As you have `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}` the axis coordinates are used as default for `\draw` and similar things inside an `axis`. Had you had a `compat` setting of lower than 1.11, or none at all, you would have to use `(axis cs:x,y)` to specify that the axis coordinate system should be used.

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,amsmath}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0:5, samples=50,grid=major, 
legend style={legend cell align=left, font=\tiny},
restrict y to domain=0:5,xlabel=$\text{Dimensione dell'input}$,
ylabel=$\text{Tempo di esecuzione}$, legend pos=north west]
\addplot [color=red]    {x};
\addplot [color=green]  {e^x-5/2*x};

\legend{$n$, $e^n-\frac{5}{2}n$}


\draw [very thick,dotted] (2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
\draw [very thick,dotted] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},e^2-5/2*2) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},e^2-5/2*2);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```