# pgfplots: New TikZ command doesn't work as expected

Tags: pgfplots

I tried to parameterize [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/365054/2288), by defining a new command, however, the result isn't as I expected. So, what is wrong/missing here?

Additionally, since I need to apply this command to many plots with different y scales, how can I make the arrow height a percentage or fraction of the whole plot height instead of positioning it at certain y value?

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    IntervalLine/.style={
        draw=black, 
        line width=1pt
    },
    IntervalArrow/.style={
    blue,
    very thick,
    {Stealth}-{Stealth}
    }
}


\newcommand{\AnnotateInterval}[3]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[IntervalLine] (#1, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (#1, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
    \draw[IntervalLine] (#2, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (#2, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
    \draw[IntervalArrow] (#1,2) -- node[above,align=center]{#3} (#2,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=5]
    \addplot[mark=none,blue] {x^2};
    \AnnotateInterval{2}{4}{some text}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are nesting a tikzpicture inside a tikzpicture. That's normally not a good idea.

Comment: Ulrike means the `AnnotateInterval` newcommand.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I followed the same approach of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27281/2288).

Comment: You didn't. In the other answer the command isn't used inside another tikzpicture.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer My bad. I will try to make my code right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the output of your code more sensible, just remove `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `\end{tikzpicture}` from the `\AnnotateInterval` macro, as the comments have discussed.

If you want the arrow with text at a fraction of the height of the axis, you can for example use the approach in the below code, where I modified the `\AnnotateInterval` macro to take four arguments, instead of three, where the third is the the fractional height of the arrow.

`rel axis cs:` means that the following coordinates use relative axis coordinates, i.e. (0,0) is the lower left corner of the axis, and (1,1) is the upper right.

One thing you should be aware of: In the code you have `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}`. If the version specified here had been `1.10` or earlier, the macro as specified would not have worked properly inside the `axis` environment, because the coordinates would not have been corresponding to the axis values. To make the code work with earlier `compat` settings, you need to change the coordinates from `(x,y)` to `(axis cs:x,y)`. Starting with `compat=1.11`, the default coordinate system is `axis cs`, so specifying it explicitly is not needed.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    IntervalLine/.style={
        draw=black, 
        line width=1pt
    },
    IntervalArrow/.style={
    blue,
    very thick,
    {Stealth}-{Stealth}
    }
}


\newcommand{\AnnotateInterval}[4]{
    \draw[IntervalLine] (#1, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (#1, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
    \draw[IntervalLine] (#2, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (#2, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
    \coordinate (tmp) at (rel axis cs:0,#3);
    \draw[IntervalArrow] (#1,2 |- tmp) -- node[above,align=center]{#4} (#2,2 |- tmp);
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=5]
    \addplot[mark=none,blue] {x^2};
    \AnnotateInterval{2}{4}{0.2}{some text}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks. May I know the meaning of `rel axis cs`? or where can I find it in the manual? Additionally, number `2` in `(#1,2 |- tmp)` doesn't change the output when I change it another number. What does this `2` exactly do?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou Most PDF reader have a search function, so finding it shouldn't be hard. But I edited my answer to say quickly what that means.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou The `2` in that case is irrelevant. The coordinate specification `(x,y |- u,v)`, is the same as `(x,v)`, i.e. the x-value of the first coordinate and the y-value of the second is used.

Comment: I appreciate your comprehensive response.